# connected d flip flop, propagation time = hold time?

Tags: flipflop

When we connect two d flip flops,

the propagation time and hold time have to be the same?

or the propagation time have to be bigger than the hold time?

I'm really confused please help!!

Comment: give us a diagram, what are your requirements? What behaviour do you WANT? Have you read the nice and fancy article on Wikipedia about Flip Flop timing characteristics? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Setup.2C_hold.2C_recovery.2C_removal_times

Comment: From that article: "When cascading flip-flops which share the same clock (as in a shift register), it is important to ensure that the tCO of a preceding flip-flop is longer than the hold time (th) of the following flip-flop, so data present at the input of the succeeding flip-flop is properly "shifted in" following the active edge of the clock." When they say tCO they mean the time from clock to output, aka - the propagation delay.

Comment: thank you for your comments!! I better go and read the article again

Answer (score 1):

The hold time is the time a stable input must be presented before you know it will be read properly.
The propagation time is the time the output will give a stable output signal since the input was presented with a new value.
So the propagation time will be larger then hold time.